# Shared Element Transition on ListView item click

Tags: animation, transition, element, shared

I want to perform a shared element transition whenever a list view item click is performed. This shared element transition will be of my floating action button in the main activity, to the floating action button in the edit note activity. By the way, the floating action button already has a shared element transition to it but its for launching a different activity (add note activity). Please be elaborate as I'm a newbie. Please share elaborate code.

Answer (score 0):

I found it !! Its making a new method which has all the shared element transition work and calling it inside of listview item click as it's not directly callable from a subclass.